# ag-Grid increment cell value after button click

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm working with ag-grid I have a table that looks like the one provided [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-field-k12ytn?file=/src/App.js). In my own project, I am using an external api that will receive a real item. I need to update the Received Quantity after the done. Unfortunately, the api doesn't return anything other an a status code. So I can't do something like remove the row and a new row and this particular endpoint is also throttled heavily so I can't just refetch the list over and over to update it (which probably isn't a good idea anyway).

My plan was to just take the current value in Received Quantity and increment the cell myself. I can't seem to get it right and I just out of ideas of how I can possibly do that (I know it's probably simple by brain is just fried).

I'd really appreciate it if anything who's done this can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up figuring this one out after a couple days not thinking about it. So I'll answer my own question for anyone who needs to know in the future.

I was trying to ["edit"](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/cell-editing/) the data when I really needed to ["update"](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/data-update-single-row-cell/#updating-rows--cells-example) it.

Essentially, every row in your grid will have a RowNode. You can access this node from the params of the row . Every is RowNode is indexed and has a setDataValue function which you can use to update entire rows or single cells. Click the update link above to reach the relevant documentation.